# different torch tensor multiplication get Inconsistent output

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication, tensor

first define two matrix

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(2, 5)
a = torch.randn(5, 20)
```

then perform different matrix multiplication

```
print(float(x.matmul(a)[0][0]))
print(float((x@a)[0][0]))
print(float(torch.concat((x@a[:,:1],x@a[:,1:]),dim=-1)[0][0]))
print(float(torch.concat((x[:1,:]@a,x[1:,:]@a),dim=0)[0][0]))
```

I got two different results.
The first three lines got 0.3176284730434418 while the last line got 0.3176284432411194.
There is precision issue here, anybody know why?